# How do you set different height/width for iframe in fancybox V2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have been using Fancybox 1.3.4, and right there I have the dimensions of the iframe in the link itself.

Here is an example of how I have it

```
test.html?width=675&height=470
```

When I click on the link fancybox will open the iframe with those dimensions. I am trying Fancybox V2, but I'm confused on how to set the dimensions for the iframes. I want every iframe to have different dimensions. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Set your html (with HTML5 `DOCTYPE`) like this:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-width="675" data-height="470" href="test.html" >test</a>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-width="400" data-height="200" href="test2.html" >test 2</a>
```

(set `width` and `height` on the `data-` attributes for each element)

then this script:

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  fitToView: false,
  afterLoad: function(){
   this.width = $(this.element).data("width");
   this.height = $(this.element).data("height");
  }
 }); // fancybox
```

should do the trick in fancybox v2.x

Comment: -@JFK interesting. This works in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari and IE7. I'm having a problem, however, with IE 8 & 9 adding height (bottom about 10-20px) to the div containing the link.

Comment: @Chris22 got any link? does it happen the same in this demo http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/getDimensionFromIframe_27may12.html?