# Different iFrame dimensions for different iFrame calls using FancyBox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using FancyBox ver 2 and it is working fine.  I am using iFrames to display two different pages using FancyBox.

However, I want to pass the dimensions of the two different iFrames as I want different sized overlays to open up.

I have no idea how to accomplish this.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });


});
    </script>
```

And these are the two links that I want to use different dimensions for:

```
<div id="top-right"><a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="contactform/contact.php" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe"><img style="padding-bottom:5px;" src="emailus.png" title="Click here to email us" /></a></div>
```

and

```
I agree to <a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="terms.html" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe">Terms of Use</a>
```

Any help on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10133055/1055987

Comment: Thanx JFK. The second link did the trick. I have no idea how to accept your response as the ANSWER as it is a "comment".

Comment: The first and the second links point actually to the same post, the first just points directly to the answer. Not need to accept any answer since this is a duplicated question.